# What does the <Page: View> do in struct PageView<Page: View>?

Tags: swift

As a Swift newbie, I'm trying to understand...

- What is happening when `<Page: View>` (or anything enclosed in `< >`) is added after a struct name?
- What is the name of this syntax?
- Is this explained in the Swift documentation (where?), or perhaps derived from C/C++?

Comment: [Generics — The Swift Programming Language (Swift 5.2)](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Generics.html)

Comment: I believe you are referring to SwiftUI. In Swift, it means you are declaring type/protocol inheritance or defining a generic type "<T>". Maybe that will give you a place to start.

Comment: Btw, you may want to tag this with `SwiftUI`

Comment: Interesting, I actually did tag the original post with swiftui. ‍♂️

Comment: Oh, @Asperi removed the tag I think. :)

Comment: SwiftUI is UI framework based on swift language. There is nothing here about SwiftUI itself, generics and protocols are a swift language core features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the direction pointed by @Asperi in the comments, I think I'm able to answer my own question.

The name for this language construct is [generics](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Generics.html).

In the first example below, `Page` defines a *generic type*, a placeholder name for a type. The `page` parameter can store a value in any valid Swift type. `Page` could be any name that makes sense for the readibility of your code.

```
struct PageView<Page> {
    var page: Page
}
```

In the second example below, `View` is a *type constraint* and is used to restrict the possible types assignable to the `page` parameter. In this example, the generic Page type must adhere to the the SwiftUI [View](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view) protocol. Whatever is assigned to `page` must implement everything required by the View protocol.

```
struct PageView<Page: View> {
    var page: Page
}
```